# Does the facility layout problem with zero and one matrices have a specific name?

Tags: combinatorial-optimization, facility-location, terminology

I have an facility layout problem where the flow between any two departments is either zero or one. Also the distance between each location pair has the same nature (zero or one). I am curious whether the problem with that specific nature has another name so that specific solving methods can be found rather than the original facility layout problem ones.

Answer (score 1):

In the real situation, usually, this is not important how you could define the input matrices either by float numbers or binary numbers. The most important thing is that these matrices most show the applicable factors of the facility such as, material flow, the distance between the departments or whose related cost/time.

If you have a binary matrix for input data, it might be interesting to change those results in an objective function sense (e.g. cost or time). After that, you can use some useful traditional algorithms like CRAFT, CORELAP, etc. or solving your problem by developing a mathematical programme.